# Can't see if CanClick is false in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have following wpf:

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkStyle" TargetType="Hyperlink">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"      
            Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>

<TextBlock>                 
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Mode=OneTime}"      
               Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyle}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                       
            <Image Margin="0,2,2,0" Source="{Binding Icon}" />         
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />                   
        </StackPanel>                
    </Hyperlink>            
</TextBlock>
```

The problem is that you can't see if CanClick on the ClickCommand is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the hyperlink's command is false, it is disabled (IsEnabled should be false). Check that this is the case and that the child items also are disabled. Did you try finding where it fails? For example, remove your custom style or the child elements (replace them with a simple text), so you can see where the problem is.

Edit:
So the style is the problem. In that case, try inheriting from the default style:

```
<Style
    x:Key="HyperlinkStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
```

Comment: If I remove the custom style it works. But then the text is blue, and I want it to be black.

Comment: It solved the problem. Thanks. But how do I do so that the icon is grayed out.

Comment: The reason is that the "disabled" look is done by modifying the Foreground and/or text color to gray. A WPF image has no "disabled look" (unfortunately), so you have to do it yourself. See http://apocryph.org/2007/08/26/rendering_disabled_grayed_out_image_buttons_wpf/ for example.